# DNS Scavenging - "This zone can be scavenged after" time stamp missing

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-server-2003

I am setting up DNS scavenging on a Windows 2003 server. When I go to set up scavenging on a zone the "This zone can be scavenged after" time stamp box is blank and not editable. Is this intended behavior? I thought this box should have todays date and time.

Thanks in advance for any advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The box indeed should have a timestamp (not necessarily the current one) if you have you enabled both - dynamic updates *and* scavenging - for the zone in question. It should *not* be editable at any time.

> When you first set scavenging on a zone the timestamp seen at the bottom (reload zone if you don't see it) will be set to the current time of day rounded down to the nearest hour plus the Refresh interval.  This also gets reset any time the zone is loaded or any time dynamic updates get enabled on the zone.

(From: http://blogs.technet.com/b/networking/archive/2008/03/19/don-t-be-afraid-of-dns-scavenging-just-be-patient.aspx)

Comment: I have both enabled

Comment: @BigJ so have you tried reloading the zone as suggested in the quoted passage?

Comment: I did and now it works. I'm a dumby. Thanks mucho!